# Using Expresso store in a responsive design

Tags: expresso-store

I'm looking for an ecommerce solution to use with EE but I need to be able to use it within a responsive design. I don't see anything in the docs as to what markup is output with a cart tag or checkout tag. From the "showcase" sites on the website, it looks like the cart is a table and the checkout is a simple form. Is this the case?

I've built a responsive ecommerce site using Foxycart before and had to override a lot of their CSS, but got it working. How much control does the developer have over the markup and styling of the cart, checkout and other basic templates or tags?

Is there a vanilla install somewhere out there to look at the code?

Thanks.

Comment: I am currently using expresso store together with Foundation 5 which handles the responsiveness of my site. Works great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store like ExpressionEngine does not make any assumptions about your template content. The checkout tag and product tags will create an opening and closing `<form>` tag but other then that you are free to arrange your template however you see fit. There are no predesignated styles or html elements that you need to use or create.

When you purchase Store there is a set of example templates that you can use but the actual html portion is completely up to you.

Comment: Thank you. How about the cart tag? What does that output? Is it output as tabular data by default?

Comment: It outputs whatever you tell it to. See the example in the docs: https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/cart_tag.html You just put the variables where you want them in the HTML you wrote.

Comment: The cart tag does not output a `<form>` tag because it is meant to just show the contents of the cart not allow for you to change quantitates or remove items from the cart. Other then that it does not make any assumptions of your content.